# ASUS Zenbook UM3402YA Sound not working

Tags: linux, audio, firmware, asus, cirrus-logic

Has anyone managed to fix the lack of sound on [Asus Zenbook UM3402YA](https://www.asus.com/laptops/for-home/zenbook/zenbook-14-oled-um3402/)?

I believe that [CS35L41](https://www.cirrus.com/products/cs35l41/) is the one causing the trouble, it's a sound amplifier that has firmware support under Windows but sadly none under Linux.

I tried literally everything I could find related to this model not producing sound under Linux.

There seems like some development has happened in the latest kernels, but even using them doesn't solve a thing for me.

Sound under Windows works without an issue.

I appreciate any help a lot

```
{ 04:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
04:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor (rev 01)
04:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller }
{ snd_seq_dummy          16384  0
snd_hrtimer            16384  1
snd_seq               110592  7 snd_seq_dummy
snd_seq_device         16384  1 snd_seq
snd_ctl_led            24576  0
snd_acp3x_rn           16384  3
snd_soc_dmic           16384  1
snd_acp3x_pdm_dma      16384  1
snd_sof_amd_rembrandt    16384  0
snd_sof_amd_renoir     16384  0
snd_sof_amd_acp        61440  2 snd_sof_amd_rembrandt,snd_sof_amd_renoir
snd_sof_pci            24576  2 snd_sof_amd_rembrandt,snd_sof_amd_renoir
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     20480  1 snd_sof_amd_acp
snd_sof               385024  2 snd_sof_amd_acp,snd_sof_pci
snd_hda_codec_realtek   196608  1
snd_sof_utils          20480  1 snd_sof
snd_hda_codec_generic   110592  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_soc_core          438272  4 snd_acp3x_rn,snd_sof,snd_soc_dmic,snd_acp3x_pdm_dma
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     94208  1
snd_compress           32768  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      20480  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_intel          65536  8
snd_pci_ps             20480  0
snd_intel_dspcfg       36864  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof
snd_rpl_pci_acp6x      20480  0
snd_acp_pci            16384  0
ledtrig_audio          16384  3 snd_ctl_led,snd_hda_codec_generic,asus_wmi
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_pci_acp6x          20480  0
snd_hda_codec         221184  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_pci_acp5x          20480  0
snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41_spi    16384  0
snd_rn_pci_acp3x       24576  0
snd_hda_core          139264  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
regmap_spi             16384  1 snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41_spi
snd_acp_config         16384  4 snd_rn_pci_acp3x,snd_sof_amd_rembrandt,snd_acp_pci,snd_sof_amd_renoir
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41_i2c    16384  0
snd_soc_acpi           16384  2 snd_sof_amd_acp,snd_acp_config
snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41    49152  2 snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41_i2c,snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41_spi
snd_pcm               221184  13 snd_sof_amd_acp,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pci_acp6x,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_sof_utils,snd_hda_core,snd_acp3x_pdm_dma,snd_pci_ps,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_pci_acp3x          20480  0
snd_hda_cs_dsp_ctls    20480  1 snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41
cs_dsp                 77824  2 snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41,snd_hda_cs_dsp_ctls
snd_timer              53248  3 snd_seq,snd_hrtimer,snd_pcm
snd_soc_cs35l41_lib    40960  3 snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41_i2c,snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41,snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41_spi
snd                   155648  40 snd_ctl_led,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof,snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_hda_cs_dsp_ctls
soundcore              16384  2 snd_ctl_led,snd }
```

Added outputs of the requested commands. Using updated OpenSuse Tumbleweed and Kernel 6.2.0-1-default.

Thanks for the support so far!
I did try the methods proposed in the post, however with no success, just installed the OS mentioned above to start from a clean slate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No sound from internal speakers on laptop, but headphone jack and HDMI works](https://superuser.com/questions/1719920/no-sound-from-internal-speakers-on-laptop-but-headphone-jack-and-hdmi-works)

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Could you please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1771729/edit) the question to add the outputs of `sudo lspci | grep Audio` and `sudo lsmod | grep snd`? Please enclose the outputs in the code brackets `{ }` to preserve the formatting. Also knowing your OS and kernel versions might help.

Comment: No unfortunately not, i tried the steps taken there but had no success. Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: According to [Phoronix](https://www.phoronix.com/news/Linux-5.17-Cirrus-CS35L41) kernel support for CS35L41 would be added in kernel 5.17. [Here's](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/tiwai/sound.git/commit/?h=for-next&id=7b2f3eb492dac7665c75df067e4d8e4869589f4a) the kernel.org page.

Comment: I am relatively new to linux. Am I correct to assume that those changes would also be present in the newest kernel? For example i have 6.2.1 installed and still no sound.

Comment: For the future; if someone asks for more info or clarifications, it's a good practice to edit the question and add the answers. Also it's good to add things like "I had a look at the link provided by xx and..." As for your last question - yes, you're correct, the additions are cumulative when it comes to adding support for new tech. Support for outdated tech does get dropped at some point. I just now had a peek at @davidmneedham's link, and you should too. There are multiple possible solutions for you, with step-by-step instructions :-)

Comment: Thank you guys so much for the answers. I try to compile the kernel but always get errors I cant solve via searching the internet. Can someone maybe share his or her compiled kernel?