# No sound from internal speakers and headphone jack but sounds over HDMI works

Tags: ubuntu, audio, speakers

I have Huawei notebook (KLVL-WXXW-PCB) with Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS installed alongside Windows. In Ubuntu, neither internal speakers nor headphone jack work. I only see Dummy Output while trying to adjust volume, but sound works with external monitor attached via HDMI.

Internal speakers work with Windows, so I believe hardware is fine and kernel driver (snd_hda_intel) needs to be modified to fix the problem.

I have submitted bug report, but instead of just waiting I want try to fix it myself. My problem is similar to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1719920/no-sound-from-internal-speakers-on-laptop-but-headphone-jack-and-hdmi-works). I need some kernel patch, but I don't know how to write a proper one.

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards 
 0 [Generic        ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
                      HD-Audio Generic at 0xd03c0000 irq 64
 1 [acp            ]: acp - acp
                      HUAWEI-KLVL_WXXW-M1010-KLVL_WXXW_PCB
```

My laptop seems to have 2 audio Controllers (cards). Only card 0 detects HDA codec, it is HDMI one. Sound over HDMI with external monitor connected works.

```
$ ls /proc/asound/card0
codec#0  eld#0.0  eld#0.1  id  pcm3p  pcm7p
$ ls /proc/asound/card1
id  pcm0c
```

Is it possible internal speakers are wired to card1?
Solution [described here](https://github.com/codepayne/linux-sound-huawei/wiki) does not work for me. Blacklisting snd_acp3x_rn module makes card1 disappear from /proc/asound/cards. It returned after reversing blacklisting.

```
$ cat /proc/asound/modules 
0 snd_hda_intel
1 snd_acp3x_rn
```

In the meantime Windows upgraded BIOS to Version: 1.09 Release Date 06/20/2023 I presume most recent available. Has anybody tried AMD drivers for linux?

Comment: See https://forum.mxlinux.org/viewtopic.php?t=71146, https://github.com/Smoren/huawei-ubuntu-sound-fix for possible answer

Comment: I've tried this one but it does not work. The problem it solves is different: "When headphones are connected, the system considers that sound should be output from the speakers. When the headphones are off, the system tries to output sound through them.". In my case connecting headphones jack does not activate internal speakers.

Comment: So you should post the hardware specifications (you can follow the MXLinux link above to get it) by [edit]ing the question.

Comment: Thank you for editing. Mayube this? https://github.com/codepayne/linux-sound-huawei/wiki Not really sure, it may still not work for newer models. Meanwhile I suggest you try the upcoming 24.04, to be released in April so, not yet ready for "production" (and unsupported at AskUbuntu) in a live session just to see if the audio subsystem is correctly recognized with the newer kernel.